# when swing Canvas graphics initiallized?

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt

I'm studying Java Swing Now. When I try to use canvas in JFrame I met a confused situation.

I invoke `graphics.fillRect` in my code, but canvas will be reset after maybe 0.1s later. My code is here:

```
public static <T> void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("天码营贪吃蛇游戏");
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setSize(500, 500);
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    window.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setSize(500, 500);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    Graphics graphics = canvas.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(Color.black);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}
```

So when I run the code, I will see a original canvas in windows. I have tried `Thread.sleep(1000);`, then I can see a black background. Is there any thread will reset my canvas?

Comment: The thread named 'AWT-EventQueue-1' will keep repainting the canvas as necessary. Which points out another issue - the fact that all UI manipulation should happen on a designated event queue thread (in your case, it does not, and could technically cause various issues). Aside from that, answer by D. Sangs explains how to have a permanent drawing on the Canvas.

Comment: But why Thread.sleep(1000); make the code work? If 'AWT-EventQueue-1' will keep repainting the canvas as necessary, what situation is necessary?  I still fell confused by this situation.

Comment: You are depending on undefined behavior, since it is UB if you access the drawing primitives outside the designated event queue thread. So on one OS + JVM config it might work with the sleep of the main thread, elsewhere it will work differently.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried override the paint method in canvas, but it does not work.  And the code is a simplest sample, I do have any other, shall I use it in a more complex way?

Comment: Don't use a Canvas that is an AWT component. Instead use a JPanel in a Swing application. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Canvas gets repainted over and over again. You need to create a class that derives from the Canvas-Class and override its paint-Method (probably need to look the correct name up in the Javadoc). That way, it gets drawn anew everytime it is asked to repaint itself.

Comment: But I still confused when the canvas is called to repaint? If it is repaint all the time, why Thread.sleep(1000); make the code work?

Comment: I try to override the paint method, but it dosen't work. My code here:Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) { }
        };

Comment: *"why Thread.sleep(1000); make the code work?"* It doesn't really make it work in any **reliable** way. Try that code on the next VM or OS and it will likely fail. More importantly, `Thread.sleep(..)` 'freezes' the app. so it cannot respond to the user (or the OS). It's not something that should ever be done to the Event Dispatch Thread (that GUIs run on).

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g) { }` Umm.. that should be `public void paint(Graphics g) { /* Painting code goes below this comment! */ }` **Do the tutorial suggested by @camickr almost a day ago!** It explains it better than we can in code comments.